# La Optimización mata la sentencia switch que necesito usar en una función

Tags: c, optimización, stm32, switch

Hola a todos ¿como están?. Estoy haciendo un proyecto con un **STM32F103C6** *(tiene flash de 32KB)* y tuve que activar las opciones de optimización para no quedarme sin memoria, ahora mismo la opción de optimización es `-Og`. Después de activar la optimización de una función, tengo que saber la posición de una subcadena y luego estoy tratando de usar una sentencia "*switch*" que el compilador está matando, no sé por qué.

Aquí están las definiciones de funciones:

```
void Selec_Opera(char *ent, uint8_t dim)
volatile uint8_t pos = 0;
volatile uint8_t lugar = 0;
//  uint8_t com[T_COMANDO] = {0};
pos = strindex(comandos, (char *) eComando);
for(lugar = 0; T_COMANDO*lugar <= pos; lugar++)
{
    asm("nop");
}
switch(lugar)
{
case 0x01:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 0x02:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 0x03:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 0x04:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 0x05:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 0x06:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 7:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
default:
{
     lugar = 25;
}
break;
}
}


volatile uint8_t strindex(char s[], char t[])
{
uint8_t i, j, k;
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    for (j=i, k=0; t[k]!='\0' && s[j]==t[k]; j++, k++);
    if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')
    return i;
}
return -1;
}
```

y estoy llamando a `Selec_Opera()` desde el *main* como se observa más abajo:

```
while (1)
{
  if(HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive(&hi2c1, eComando, T_COMANDO, HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK)
  {
      codigoError = 20;
      Error_Handler();
  }
  else
  {
      Selec_Opera((char *) eComando, T_COMANDO);
  }
/* USER CODE END WHILE */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
}
```

La función `I2C` funciona bien, el problema está en la función `Selec_Opera()`. Si quieren saber, *T_COMANDO* se define como 4 y *eComando* es el arreglo donde estoy almacenando la trama recibida.

Cuando se está ejecutando la función `Selec_Opera()` se puede ver que casi ninguna de las opciones fueron compiladas, algunas imágenes pueden mostrar correctamente lo que estoy tratando de explicar.

La siguiente imagen muestra que cuando estoy haciendo una sesión de depuración, el archivo de depuración tiene el texto, pero al ver las opciones del "*switch*" casi ninguna fue incluida en el archivo ejecutable **(necesito esa parte)**.

[image: Opciones del switch eliminadas]

Solo fueron incluidas la opción 7 y la default, he probado el "*switch*" con opciones reducidas y el comportamiento es el mismo, solo la última opción numerada y la opción default están incluidas en el código (esto se puede ver porque a la izquierda de la imagen está escrita el posición de memoria de la instrucción)

Probé el "for" y está trabajando bien mientras selecciona la posición de la trama donde está el la *sub-trama* así que no se por qué me está pasando esto con el "*switch*".

¿Alguien puede ayudarme con esto?.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda brindada.

Comment: Esa mezcla de español e inglés en la pregunta no es necesaria. Las preguntas en SOes deben ser publicadas con texto en español.

Comment: Disculpen, no me fijé. Es que primero lo publiqué en otro foro en inglés y luego aquí, ya lo corrijo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> solo fueron incluidas la opción 7 y la default, he probado el "switch" con opciones reducidas y el comportamiento es el mismo, solo la última opción numerada

Fíjate que **todos** los `case` hacen **exactamente lo mismo**. El compilador se limita a modificar el `switch` tal que:

```
switch(lugar)
{
case 0x01:
case 0x02:
case 0x03:
case 0x04:
case 0x05:
case 0x06:
case 7:
    lugar++;
    break;
default:
    lugar = 25;
    break;
}
```

Es decir, todas las opciones siguen ahí, pero ejecutan la misma porción de código.

Le estás pidiendo justamente que optimice... y eso es lo que hace, pero el algoritmo se va a comportar exactamente igual.

Si los `case` hiciesen cosas diferentes entonces la optimización aplicada sería otra... o ninguna, pero no es el caso.

Por otro lado, si el for no debe tener cuerpo puedes dejarlo así:

```
for(lugar = 0; T_COMANDO*lugar <= pos; lugar++) ;
//                                              ^
```

Salvo que ese `nop` que le metes tenga algún otro significado especial, es totalmente innecesario.

De hecho, salvo que sea por cuestiones de tiempo, incluso el `for` podría ser reemplazado por una simple división:

```
int lugar = pos/T_COMANDO + 1;
```

Las divisiones de tipo `int` eliminan los decimales, con lo que el resultado aparece automáticamente truncado. Como el bucle se repite incluso cuando `lugar*T_COMANDO == pos`, basta con sumarle uno al resultado de la división

```
pos = 25
T_COMANDO = 4
lugar = 25 / 4 + 1 = 6 + 1 = 7
```

Comment: Gracias @eferion, casualmente ayer estaba leyendo en un libro esa forma en la que trabaja el switch donde se pueden poner varias condiciones juntas si se ejecuta el mismo código pero nunca lo relacioné con la optimización. En relación al for es que este último se detiene cuando encuentra la posición donde está la sub-trama, en otras palabras, está haciendo lo mismo que si estuviera usando un while.

Comment: Ahora tengo otra pregunta, tengo claro que colocándole el prefijo volatile evito que el compilador optimice las variables "pos" y "lugar" pero no entiendo por qué las está optimizando, las está optimizando porque no las retorno de la función o por alguna otra causa?

Comment: @vram volatile sirve para que el compilador no almacene una copia del valor de la variable en un registro del sistema, sino que fuerzas a que **siempre** se consulte la posición de memoria de la variable. Es una palabra pensada para entornos multihilo donde el valor de la variable podría cambiar en cualquier momento... en cuyo caso el valor almacenado en el registro no se sincronizaría

Comment: @vram así que, efectivamente, no tiene demasiado sentido usar esa palabra con variables locales

Comment: pero el problema que tengo ahí es que si no uso el prefijo volatile entonces el compilador me eliminas ambas variables de la misma forma que estaba eliminando los casos del switch y como consecuencia también me elimina el switch, en este caso eliminando el switch por completo. Llegué a pensar en ese caso que el compilador las eliminaba ya que no las retorno de la función, por qué las elimina?

Comment: @vram las elimina porque son variables que no usas absolutamente para nada. Los valores almacenados en `lugar ` no se usan para nada, en consecuencia el `switch` se puede eliminar... no afecta al resultado de la función